# Having Problems Installing eth-Brownie with pip

Tags: brownie

I have been struggeling installing brownie for while now and i cant seem to figure it out. I am quite new to all of this so all help is appreciated:) Running python 3.9.11. Using a an m2 mac with Ventura 13.0. Sorry if i am asking a stupid question.

```
    soldal@Sigves-MacBook-Air ~ % python3 -m pip install eth-brownie
    Collecting eth-brownie
      Using cached eth_brownie-1.19.3-py3-none-any.whl (232 kB)
    Collecting aiohttp==3.8.3 (from eth-brownie)
      Using cached aiohttp-3.8.3-cp39-cp39-macosx_11_0_arm64.whl (337 kB)
    Collecting aiosignal==1.2.0 (from eth-brownie)
      Using cached aiosignal-1.2.0-py3-none-any.whl (8.2 kB)
    Collecting asttokens==2.0.5 (from eth-brownie)
      Using cached asttokens-2.0.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl (20 kB)
    Collecting async-timeout==4.0.2 (from eth-brownie)
      Using cached async_timeout-4.0.2-py3-none-any.whl (5.8 kB)
    Collecting attrs==22.1.0 (from eth-brownie)
      Using cached attrs-22.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (58 kB)
    Collecting base58==2.1.1 (from eth-brownie)
      Using cached base58-2.1.1-py3-none-any.whl (5.6 kB)
    Collecting bitarray==2.6.0 (from eth-brownie)
      Using cached bitarray-2.6.0-cp39-cp39-macosx_11_0_arm64.whl (104 kB)
    Collecting black==22.10.0 (from eth-brownie)
      Using cached black-22.10.0-cp39-cp39-macosx_11_0_arm64.whl (1.2 MB)
    Collecting certifi==2022.9.24 (from eth-brownie)
      Using cached certifi-2022.9.24-py3-none-any.whl (161 kB)
    Collecting charset-normalizer==2.1.1 (from eth-brownie)
      Using cached charset_normalizer-2.1.1-py3-none-any.whl (39 kB)
    Collecting click==8.1.3 (from eth-brownie)
      Using cached click-8.1.3-py3-none-any.whl (96 kB)
    Collecting cytoolz==0.12.0 (from eth-brownie)
      Using cached cytoolz-0.12.0-cp39-cp39-macosx_11_0_arm64.whl (367 kB)
    Collecting dataclassy==0.11.1 (from eth-brownie)
      Using cached dataclassy-0.11.1-py3-none-any.whl (23 kB)
    Collecting eip712==0.1.0 (from eth-brownie)
      Using cached eip712-0.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (13 kB)
    Collecting eth-abi==2.2.0 (from eth-brownie)
      Using cached eth_abi-2.2.0-py3-none-any.whl (28 kB)
    Collecting eth-account==0.5.9 (from eth-brownie)
      Using cached eth_account-0.5.9-py3-none-any.whl (101 kB)
    Collecting eth-event==1.2.3 (from eth-brownie)
      Using cached eth_event-1.2.3-py3-none-any.whl (7.3 kB)
    Collecting eth-hash[pycryptodome]==0.3.3 (from eth-brownie)
      Using cached eth_hash-0.3.3-py3-none-any.whl (8.9 kB)
    Collecting eth-keyfile==0.5.1 (from eth-brownie)
      Using cached eth_keyfile-0.5.1-py3-none-any.whl (8.3 kB)
    Collecting eth-keys==0.3.4 (from eth-brownie)
      Using cached eth_keys-0.3.4-py3-none-any.whl (21 kB)
    Collecting eth-rlp==0.2.1 (from eth-brownie)
      Using cached eth_rlp-0.2.1-py3-none-any.whl (5.0 kB)
    Collecting eth-typing==2.3.0 (from eth-brownie)
      Using cached eth_typing-2.3.0-py3-none-any.whl (6.2 kB)
    Collecting eth-utils==1.10.0 (from eth-brownie)
      Using cached eth_utils-1.10.0-py3-none-any.whl (24 kB)
    Collecting execnet==1.9.0 (from eth-brownie)
      Using cached execnet-1.9.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (39 kB)
    Collecting frozenlist==1.3.1 (from eth-brownie)
      Using cached frozenlist-1.3.1-cp39-cp39-macosx_11_0_arm64.whl (35 kB)
    Collecting hexbytes==0.2.3 (from eth-brownie)
      Using cached hexbytes-0.2.3-py3-none-any.whl (6.4 kB)
    Collecting hypothesis==6.27.3 (from eth-brownie)
      Using cached hypothesis-6.27.3-py3-none-any.whl (384 kB)
    Requirement already satisfied: idna==3.4 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from eth-brownie) (3.4)
    Collecting inflection==0.5.0 (from eth-brownie)
      Using cached inflection-0.5.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (5.8 kB)
    Collecting iniconfig==1.1.1 (from eth-brownie)
      Using cached iniconfig-1.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (5.0 kB)
    Collecting ipfshttpclient==0.8.0a2 (from eth-brownie)
      Using cached ipfshttpclient-0.8.0a2-py3-none-any.whl (82 kB)
    Collecting jsonschema==3.2.0 (from eth-brownie)
      Using cached jsonschema-3.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (56 kB)
    Collecting lazy-object-proxy==1.7.1 (from eth-brownie)
      Using cached lazy-object-proxy-1.7.1.tar.gz (41 kB)
      Installing build dependencies ... done
      Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
      Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
    Collecting lru-dict==1.1.8 (from eth-brownie)
      Using cached lru-dict-1.1.8.tar.gz (10 kB)
      Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
    Collecting multiaddr==0.0.9 (from eth-brownie)
      Using cached multiaddr-0.0.9-py2.py3-none-any.whl (16 kB)
    Collecting multidict==6.0.2 (from eth-brownie)
      Using cached multidict-6.0.2-cp39-cp39-macosx_11_0_arm64.whl (29 kB)
    Collecting mypy-extensions==0.4.3 (from eth-brownie)
      Using cached mypy_extensions-0.4.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (4.5 kB)
    Collecting mythx-models==1.9.1 (from eth-brownie)
      Using cached mythx_models-1.9.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (82 kB)
    Collecting netaddr==0.8.0 (from eth-brownie)
      Using cached netaddr-0.8.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.9 MB)
    Collecting packaging==21.3 (from eth-brownie)
      Using cached packaging-21.3-py3-none-any.whl (40 kB)
    Collecting parsimonious==0.8.1 (from eth-brownie)
      Using cached parsimonious-0.8.1.tar.gz (45 kB)
      Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
    Collecting pathspec==0.10.1 (from eth-brownie)
      Using cached pathspec-0.10.1-py3-none-any.whl (27 kB)
    Collecting platformdirs==2.5.2 (from eth-brownie)
      Using cached platformdirs-2.5.2-py3-none-any.whl (14 kB)
    Collecting pluggy==1.0.0 (from eth-brownie)
      Using cached pluggy-1.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (13 kB)
    Collecting prompt-toolkit==3.0.31 (from eth-brownie)
      Using cached prompt_toolkit-3.0.31-py3-none-any.whl (382 kB)
    Collecting protobuf==3.19.5 (from eth-brownie)
      Using cached protobuf-3.19.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl (162 kB)
    Collecting psutil==5.9.2 (from eth-brownie)
      Using cached psutil-5.9.2.tar.gz (479 kB)
      Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
    Collecting py==1.11.0 (from eth-brownie)
      Using cached py-1.11.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (98 kB)
    Collecting py-solc-ast==1.2.9 (from eth-brownie)
      Using cached py_solc_ast-1.2.9-py3-none-any.whl (10 kB)
    Collecting py-solc-x==1.1.1 (from eth-brownie)
      Using cached py_solc_x-1.1.1-py3-none-any.whl (15 kB)
    Collecting pycryptodome==3.15.0 (from eth-brownie)
      Using cached pycryptodome-3.15.0.tar.gz (4.5 MB)
      Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
    Collecting pygments==2.13.0 (from eth-brownie)
      Using cached Pygments-2.13.0-py3-none-any.whl (1.1 MB)
    Collecting pygments-lexer-solidity==0.7.0 (from eth-brownie)
      Using cached pygments-lexer-solidity-0.7.0.tar.gz (7.3 kB)
      Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
    Collecting pyjwt==1.7.1 (from eth-brownie)
      Using cached PyJWT-1.7.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (18 kB)
    Collecting pyparsing==3.0.9 (from eth-brownie)
      Using cached pyparsing-3.0.9-py3-none-any.whl (98 kB)
    Collecting pyrsistent==0.18.1 (from eth-brownie)
      Using cached pyrsistent-0.18.1-cp39-cp39-macosx_10_9_universal2.whl (81 kB)
    Collecting pytest==6.2.5 (from eth-brownie)
      Using cached pytest-6.2.5-py3-none-any.whl (280 kB)
    Collecting pytest-forked==1.4.0 (from eth-brownie)
      Using cached pytest_forked-1.4.0-py3-none-any.whl (4.9 kB)
    Collecting pytest-xdist==1.34.0 (from eth-brownie)
      Using cached pytest_xdist-1.34.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (36 kB)
    Collecting python-dateutil==2.8.1 (from eth-brownie)
      Using cached python_dateutil-2.8.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (227 kB)
    Collecting python-dotenv==0.16.0 (from eth-brownie)
      Using cached python_dotenv-0.16.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (18 kB)
    Collecting pythx==1.6.1 (from eth-brownie)
      Using cached pythx-1.6.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (39 kB)
    Collecting pyyaml==5.4.1 (from eth-brownie)
      Using cached PyYAML-5.4.1.tar.gz (175 kB)
      Installing build dependencies ... done
      Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
      error: subprocess-exited-with-error
      
      × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
      │ exit code: 1
      ╰─> [62 lines of output]
          /private/var/folders/8j/rb_4l20515xczszh2kx5qk540000gn/T/pip-build-env-ybsrvz33/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/config/setupcfg.py:293: _DeprecatedConfig: Deprecated config in `setup.cfg`
          !!
          
                  ********************************************************************************
                  The license_file parameter is deprecated, use license_files instead.
          
                  By 2023-Oct-30, you need to update your project and remove deprecated calls
                  or your builds will no longer be supported.
          
                  See https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/declarative_config.html for details.
                  ********************************************************************************
          
          !!
            parsed = self.parsers.get(option_name, lambda x: x)(value)
          running egg_info
          writing lib3/PyYAML.egg-info/PKG-INFO
          writing dependency_links to lib3/PyYAML.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
          writing top-level names to lib3/PyYAML.egg-info/top_level.txt
          Traceback (most recent call last):
            File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
              main()
            File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 335, in main
              json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
            File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 118, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
              return hook(config_settings)
            File "/private/var/folders/8j/rb_4l20515xczszh2kx5qk540000gn/T/pip-build-env-ybsrvz33/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 355, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
              return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=['wheel'])
            File "/private/var/folders/8j/rb_4l20515xczszh2kx5qk540000gn/T/pip-build-env-ybsrvz33/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 325, in _get_build_requires
              self.run_setup()
            File "/private/var/folders/8j/rb_4l20515xczszh2kx5qk540000gn/T/pip-build-env-ybsrvz33/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 341, in run_setup
              exec(code, locals())
            File "<string>", line 271, in <module>
            File "/private/var/folders/8j/rb_4l20515xczszh2kx5qk540000gn/T/pip-build-env-ybsrvz33/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 103, in setup
              return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
            File "/private/var/folders/8j/rb_4l20515xczszh2kx5qk540000gn/T/pip-build-env-ybsrvz33/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/core.py", line 185, in setup
              return run_commands(dist)
            File "/private/var/folders/8j/rb_4l20515xczszh2kx5qk540000gn/T/pip-build-env-ybsrvz33/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/core.py", line 201, in run_commands
              dist.run_commands()
            File "/private/var/folders/8j/rb_4l20515xczszh2kx5qk540000gn/T/pip-build-env-ybsrvz33/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 969, in run_commands
              self.run_command(cmd)
            File "/private/var/folders/8j/rb_4l20515xczszh2kx5qk540000gn/T/pip-build-env-ybsrvz33/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 989, in run_command
              super().run_command(command)
            File "/private/var/folders/8j/rb_4l20515xczszh2kx5qk540000gn/T/pip-build-env-ybsrvz33/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 988, in run_command
              cmd_obj.run()
            File "/private/var/folders/8j/rb_4l20515xczszh2kx5qk540000gn/T/pip-build-env-ybsrvz33/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/command/egg_info.py", line 318, in run
              self.find_sources()
            File "/private/var/folders/8j/rb_4l20515xczszh2kx5qk540000gn/T/pip-build-env-ybsrvz33/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/command/egg_info.py", line 326, in find_sources
              mm.run()
            File "/private/var/folders/8j/rb_4l20515xczszh2kx5qk540000gn/T/pip-build-env-ybsrvz33/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/command/egg_info.py", line 548, in run
              self.add_defaults()
            File "/private/var/folders/8j/rb_4l20515xczszh2kx5qk540000gn/T/pip-build-env-ybsrvz33/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/command/egg_info.py", line 586, in add_defaults
              sdist.add_defaults(self)
            File "/private/var/folders/8j/rb_4l20515xczszh2kx5qk540000gn/T/pip-build-env-ybsrvz33/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/command/sdist.py", line 113, in add_defaults
              super().add_defaults()
            File "/private/var/folders/8j/rb_4l20515xczszh2kx5qk540000gn/T/pip-build-env-ybsrvz33/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/command/sdist.py", line 251, in add_defaults
              self._add_defaults_ext()
            File "/private/var/folders/8j/rb_4l20515xczszh2kx5qk540000gn/T/pip-build-env-ybsrvz33/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/command/sdist.py", line 336, in _add_defaults_ext
              self.filelist.extend(build_ext.get_source_files())
            File "<string>", line 201, in get_source_files
            File "/private/var/folders/8j/rb_4l20515xczszh2kx5qk540000gn/T/pip-build-env-ybsrvz33/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/cmd.py", line 107, in __getattr__
              raise AttributeError(attr)
          AttributeError: cython_sources
          [end of output]
      
      note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
    error: subprocess-exited-with-error
    
    × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
    │ exit code: 1
    ╰─> See above for output.
    
    note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

I am not sure what to do and would appreciate the help because I am looking to develop using solidity and brownie seems to be the best option.

I am open to tips, suggestions, and constructive criticism

Thanks in advance.:)